# How would you make a Bootstrap 3 carousel wrap to a slide other than the first?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

For example: The carousel starts at slide 0, cycles up to the last slide, slide 9, and then wraps around to a specified slide, let's say slide 3. From there it would only cycle from slide 3 - slide 9. How would I go about this?

Comment: I am not sure, but I think this answer can help you: [httр://stackoverflow.com/answers/396932/answer-to-bootstrap-3-problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43433000/how-would-you-make-a-bootstrap-3-carousel-wrap-to-a-slide-other-than-the-first)

Comment: After further digging I found an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42402642/can-a-bootstrap-carousel-rotate-through-only-some-of-the-slides